# How do I create fonts with javascript, and how portable is this?

Tags: javascript, css, fonts

I read that [Adobe has released some free web fonts](http://html.adobe.com/edge/webfonts/)

The instructions say you need to import a script like this:

```
<script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/FOO.js"></script>
```

then you will be able to write CSS like this:

```
#foo {font-family: FOO, serif;}
```

What new sourcery is this?!?

What is this trick called, and what is the browser support like?

Comment: It's called "web fonts", sort of like the title implies.

Comment: Oh and it's been implemented, in some state, since IE4 (win: 1997, mac & unix: 1998), FF 3.5 (2009), Chrome 4 (2010) and and Safari 3.1 (2007). So its really not new sorcery at all :)

Comment: typekit / font squirrel have been around for years, do some research on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me introduce you to some CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Foo';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url("foo.eot");
    src: url("foo.woff") format("woff"), url("foo.ttf") format("truetype"), url("foo.svg#foo") format("svg");
}

p {
    font-family: Foo, sans-serif;
}
```

`@font-face` defines a web font and gives it some sources to try depending on what browser you're using.  the `font-family` property tells it what you want to call it later on.

Here's the [MDN Documentation for `@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@font-face)